# OpenVPN with IPv6

Tags: openvpn, ipv6, tunnel

I have a tun OpenVPN server running in routed mode which was set up on a Ubuntu server and I know that Ubuntu's build of OpenVPN has support for the IPv6 for quite a while now but it didn't get much of my interest to fiddle around with it until my server provider recently provided me with IPv6.

So I'd like to know how do you configure OpenVPN server to enable support for IPv6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using OpenVPN 2.1 or 2.2 you can find what you're looking for [here](http://www.greenie.net/ipv6/openvpn.html).

Bernhardt Schmidt has also put together [a package for Ubuntu](https://launchpad.net/~berni/+archive/ipv6) that includes the IPv6 payload patch integrated with OpenVPN.

Since this question is old, hope this is still relevant.

Comment: +1, nice to see an old question get a good answer.

Comment: Didn't expect this would get any replies! Thanks for those useful links, though I had already seen the first one. Could be useful ref for others that want to setup ipv6 openvpn